# BUTTON - go to anchor URL 1 on hover, go to URL 2 on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am creating a 'One Page' navigation on my homepage.

I have a 'Books' button in my menu navigation.

What I'm trying to achieve is that if the visitor 'hovers' over the Books button, the homepage scrolls down to where the 'books' section is on the homepage, so this should be an anchor link - #books

But then when the user clicks the button, it will take them to the actual 'books' page - example.com/books

So I need an anchor link on hover, and regular link on click.

Is this possible?

Other that creating the regular link on click, I haven't tried much unfortunately, I don't really know where to start with the hover action.

Comment: Use mouse enter and scroll to in jquery for the hover and regular anchor for click

Comment: Thanks @EvikGhazarian, what should the jquery code look like if say my button css class is .menu-books and the section I need to scroll to on homepage is #home-books ?

Comment: When user hovers the books button and screen scrolls... what happens to the books button? Does it stay at the same place, under the mouse pointer or it scrolls away?

Comment: I'll write an answer for you but keep in mind the scroll shall delay if not the user cannot click on it

Comment: Thanks @EvikGhazarian

Comment: @NawedKhan the Books button stays exactly where it is, under the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will scroll down to the div but remember I added one second delay to the scroll so the user can click on it. you can increase/decrease delay as you wish.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div.top').mouseenter(function() {
  $('html, body').stop(true, true).delay(1000).animate({
    scrollTop: $("div.middle").offset().top
  }, 1000);
  })
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

.top {
  background-color: green;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px auto 55px auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

.middle {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <a href="http://google.com">Hover for scroll or Click for Google</a>
</div>
<div class="middle">
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, though might not be overly user-friendly (touch-screens don't have 'hovers', after all). To do this, you will need to use JavaScript, and can do something like this:

```js
// Get all 'hover' links
let hoverLinks = document.querySelectorAll('[data-scrollto]');

// Loop through, and add 'mouseenter' events
Array.from(hoverLinks).forEach(link => {
  // Add hover state
  link.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    // Find associated div
    let div = document.getElementById(link.dataset.scrollto) || null;

    // If div doesn't exist, return
    if(!div) return;

    // Scroll to div
    div.scrollIntoView(true);
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em 0;
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  z-index: 2;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3em 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="home.html">Home</a>
  <a href="books.html" data-scrollto="books-wrapper">Scroll to books</a>
</nav>

<section>
  Hello
</section>

<section>
  Hello
</section>

<section id="books-wrapper">
  BOOKS!
</section>

<section>
  Hello
</section>

<section>
  Hello
</section>
```

In short, you just need to add an event listener (in this case, a 'mouseenter' event listener) via JavaScript to the link, which when triggered (e.g. when a user hovers over the link) will search for an associated scroll position and scroll to it. For linking through to the page, this can just be done with a standard `<a href=""></a>` link.

In the above example, I used an `id` to create a unique identifier for the scroll-to location, and then saved that as a string in an attribute in the link. That way, you can re-use this event listener to add scrolls to other links too. For example, you could add an `id` of `contact` to another element on the page, and add `data-scrollto="contact"` to a new `<a>` tag to scroll this as well.

**EDIT:**

To make this more relevant:

```js
document.querySelector('.menu-button').addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  let div = document.getElementById('books-home') || null;
  
  if(!div) return;
  
  div.scrollIntoView(true);
});
```

```css
html,
body{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em 0;
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  z-index: 2;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3em 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="home.html">Home</a>
  <a href="books.html" class="menu-button">Scroll to books</a>
</nav>

<section>
  Hello
</section>

<section>
  Hello
</section>

<section id="books-home">
  BOOKS!
</section>

<section>
  Hello
</section>

<section>
  Hello
</section>
```

Comment: how would the code change if we know that the CSS class of the button is .menu-button and the ID anchor it needs to scroll to is #books-home ?

Comment: You could simply change the `querySelectorAll()` selector, and replace `div.datalist.scrollto` with `'books-home'`, though if you know all the selectors and they aren't going to change then you can trim the JavaScript right down. Please check my most recent edits to see how.